# Do any versions of Apache allow for a different declaration of SSLProtocol for different Virtual Hosts?

Tags: windows-server-2003, apache-2.4, mod-ssl

We are currently using Apache 2.4.10. For various reasons we need to drop support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on some domains, but leave 1.1 support on others.

I've been reading but can't find a definitive answer. Do any versions of Apache support different declarations of SSLProtocol for different VirtualHosts?

2.4.10 as I am sure you know only respects the first VirtualHosts declarations.

This question isn't a duplicate of the other one as it deals with Apache 2.4. The other question resulted in the answer that 2.2 does not support what I am asking about. I am asking if any version of 2.4 supports what I am asking about.

Comment: The other Q&A covers Apache 2.4. The answer remains valid as of three minutes ago. I even went to look at the bug reports to be sure.

Comment: Which would mean it does not cover the latest versions of 2.4.

Comment: Did you actually go and look, or are you simply arguing to be argumentative?

Comment: As my question outlines, I have read up on the latest versions and am seeking some clarification from someone more in the know. Funny about you suggesting I am simply being argumentative. I had the same thought about you.

Comment: I already gave you your clarification. You refused to accept it.

Comment: My bad. I read "remains valid as of three months ago". The latest versions being less old.